# HASH for GIF IMAGES

Tags: php, hash, md5, gif, sha1

I need to know if exists any form to get a unique hash from gif images, i did tried with SHA1 file function

```
sha1_file
```

but i don't know if exist the case where two hash of different gif images, result in same hash.
Its can happen with SHA1? In this case is better SHA2, or MD5? Or any other previously implemented in PHP language.

I know its also depends of file size, but gifs image don't exceed 10mb in any case.

I need recommendations for this problem. best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hash function that creates different values for each and every set of images you provide. This should be obvious as your hash values are much shorter than the files themselves and therefore they are bound to drop some information on the way. Given a *fixed* set of images it is rather simple to produce a perfect hash function (e.g. by numbering them), but this is probably not the answer you are looking for.

On the other hand you can use "perfect hashing", a two step hashing algorithm that guarantees amortized O(1) *access* using a two step hashing algorithm, but as you are asking for a unique 'hash' that may also not be what you are looking for. Could you be a bit more specific about why you insist on the hash-value being unique and under what circumstances?

Comment: I want to generate a database of gif images, but i want to only store the hash, and then compare with the user image, and provide information about the gif. I need to know if the same gif image..

Comment: Well, as pointed out in the probability calculations above, to be *really* sure you will have to store the whole picture you will have to store it and compare the pictures *if (and only if)* the hash values are equal. Given the size of an SHA1 hash value the probability of a collision is ridiculously low for any practical purposes. Given you want to *store* your pictures in a database they should be hanging around anyways, but you should be free to use the hash as an *index* to find the right image quickly (which is the point of a hash function usually).

Answer (score 0):

`sha1_file` is fine.

In theory you can run into two files that hash to the same value, but in practice it is so stupendously unlikely that you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions don't provide any guarantees about uniqueness. [Patru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22431111/23897) explains why, very well - this is the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if you'd like to read up.

I'd like to talk about another aspect, though. While you won't get any theoretical guarantees, you get a practical guarantee. Consider this: SHA-256 generates hashes that are 256 bits long. That means there are 2<sup>256</sup> possible hashes it can generate. Assume further that the hashes it generates are distributed almost purely randomly (true for SHA-256). That means that if you generate a billion hashes a second, 24 hours a day, you'll have generated 31,536,000,000,000,000 hashes a year. A lot, right?

Divide that by 2<sup>256</sup>. That's ~10<sup>60</sup>. If you walked linearly through all possible hashes, that's how many *years* it would take you to generate all possible hashes (pack a lunch). Divide that by two, that's... still ~10<sup>60</sup>. That's how many years you'd have to work to have a greater than 50% chance of generating the same hash twice.

To put it another way, if you generate a billion hashes a second for a century, you'd have a 1/10<sup>58</sup> chance of generating the same hash twice. Until the sun burns out, 1/10<sup>50</sup>.

Those are damn fine chances.

Comment: Well, you are right about how long it will take you to generate another picture with the same hash-value as a given picture (on average), you will have to try half the numbers of hash values. However if you consider the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) it will only take you about roughly the square root of the total number of hash values to generate the *same* number twice. The probability ist still in the 2**-128=2.93e-39 which will still take about 10e20 years, but that is a lot less :-)